# Visiting Girlfriend in the USA for 10 days on a ESTA from the UK London (I am 30 years old)

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, esta

What was your experience like with US immigration when you told the CPB officer you are there to visit your boyfriend/girlfriend for a short period?

This will be my 2nd time but previously I have always said visiting Family but I don’t feel comfortable lying

Comment: How long ago was your last visit, and how long was it? Did you ever stay longer than what you told on arrival? Do you have a job, a house or flat to return to?

Comment: You can just say you visit 'a friend'. Her gender is not of relevance.

Comment: @jcaron it has been 2-3 months since my last visit and no i did not stay long than what i told on arrival (it was 10 days) yes I do work full time as a technical engineer, living with parents

Comment: If ever they ask more questions it should be quite quick. Just make sure you have a printout of your return ticket at hand (they probably already have it on their screen anyway) and know the date and that should be about it. Just answer the questions they ask and you’ll quickly be on your way.

Answer (score 7):

**Tell the truth.** If you have a return ticket, a job to return to, money to cover your expenses and generally don't look like you're planning to illegally work or overstay in the US, you'll be fine.

Comment: They may search your baggage to find evidence that you plan to work, or that degrades the plausibility of your story.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey thanks for the info! Thats fine I don’t plan to bring anything that would suggests this… just clothing!

Comment: @Bobodon - happens a lot at the UK border - printed CV/resumes, notes of prospective employers, even diaries containing things like 'tomorrow I start my new life in Britain!'.

Comment: @Bobodon - also smartphones, social media, etc.